# Download the datasets from torchvision. Differences between the argument?

Tags: pytorch

For example it is written for the `CelebA` dataset:

```
torchvision.datasets.CelebA(root, split='train', download=False)
```

While for CIFAR there is writing:

```
torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root, train=True, download=False)
```

My question is: what is the difference between `train=true` and `split=train`?

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html) it depends according to the dataset you're using.

For instance for the CIFAR dataset you have no parameters`split` in the docs, whereas CELEBA has no `train` parameters.

This is a choice made by the ones that wrote the library and as you can read in the docs there is no norms about those parameters, it really depends on the dataset you want to use.